# Using voice recognition with latest pebble sdk?

Tags: voice-recognition, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

In the latest pebble time there is a mic implemented. This can be used to answer on messages coming from the phone by voice which will be transcribed and send back to the sender as an answer.

Is there a possibility to use the voice command/voice recognition in own pebble apps as well? I have found no info about that.

Thank you!

Comment: I think a lot of developers would like to be able to capture audio from the mic, but unfortunately Pebble has not added support for this in their SDK (yet). I guess you could reverse engineer a solution by looking at the CPU data sheet and experimenting, but it would take considerable time and effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [dictation API](http://developer.getpebble.com/guides/pebble-apps/sensors/dictation/) in applications.